# Using java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock instead of Synchronized: can my code avoid dead-lock in a bank transfer scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, deadlock

I was looking into measures to avoid dead-lock, where a possible way is to break the cyclic-waiting by force a thread to give up the lock it already holds when it is accessing another lock but the lock is unaccessible.

Given a simplest bank account transfer as an example:

```java
class Account {
  private int balance;
 
  void transfer(Account target, int amt){
    //lock the from account
    synchronized(this) {              
      //lock the to account
      synchronized(target) {           
        if (this.balance > amt) {
          this.balance -= amt;
          target.balance += amt;
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

When using nested synchronized blocks, when a thread is holding the monitor of the current account, when it cannot access the lock of target account, it will be blocked until the lock is available and will not be able to response to any interruption. It won't have chance to try first whether the second lock is available so that won't have chance to give up the lock it already holds.
While Lock interface provides the `tryLock()` method which can supports the scenario seamlessly
. It also provides the `lockInterruptibly()` which means when it get blocked due to inaccessibility of the second lock, it can still response to interruption. But what I am wondering is that when interrupted, what ensures the thread will throw away all the locks it already holds? Since I didn't find a doc anywhere like `Object.wait()` which has docs saying explicitly it will relinquish all synchronization it holds. Besides the `Thread.interrupt()` is simply calling a native method which I cannot see any implementation.
Well I can understand it by instinct that the locks must be released otherwise after the thread being interrupted no other thread will be able to access the lock but I just wish to know what exactly happens by my own.

---

**updated:**
As @Holger has pointed  out, I made a mistake in understanding what `Object.wait()` did when the monitor is not accessible. And I have tried to make a lock solution for this scenario, but I am not sure if it has some fallacies or not. Hope someone can point it out should there are errors in the code.
And also I wish to know if my code can possibly handle  may proposed scenario.
Below is the code:

```java
    class Account {
        private int balance;
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        void transfer(Account target, int amt) {
            //lock the from account
            try {
                if (lock.tryLock(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    if (target.lock.tryLock(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        this.balance -= amt;
                        target.balance += amt;
                        target.lock.unlock();
                    }
                    lock.unlock();
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted while attempting the lock.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I will appreciate a lot if someone can give an sample on how to deal with the situation using `lockInterruptibly()`.

Comment: Do you have code sample using Lock?

Comment: First of all, `Object.wait` does *not* relinquish “all synchronization it holds”. It will only release the monitor associated with the object, it invoked `wait` on. In case of nested, different monitors, it will *not* release the other(s). For `lockInterruptibly()`, the answer is even simpler. It does not release any locks. You are confusing interruption with notification. `wait` has to release the associated monitor, to allow another thread to fulfill the condition and call `notify`. In contrast, interruption is not dependent on any lock.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for rectify my misunderstanding. Yeah I did check jdk doc which says "This method causes the current thread to
 place itself in the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object.". So it means  what will be relinquish are all synchronization on the monitor object right?

Comment: @Holger So if  I use `lockInterruptibly()`, a thread got the current account's lock but not the target account's lock for a longtime, we can simply allow the thread to interrupt itself right, since intteruption is not dependent on lock, is it correct?

Comment: @DuncG Can you help me check if my lock code can solve my proposed scenario and are there any potential fallacy that I am not aware of? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A thread can not interrupt itself when it is blocked. Only other threads can interrupt it.

Comment: Your example code is broken, as it calls `unlock`, regardless of whether `tryLock` was successful or not. You *must not* call `unlock` when you don’t own the lock.

Comment: @Holger If only other threads can interrupt the blocked thread, how can they know the name of the blocked thread?

Comment: That’s up to your application logic. Why do you want to interrupt the thread?

Comment: @Holger When it holds a partial resource for a long time which increase possibility of dead-lock. also I just updated my code, will it work this time?

Comment: When it holds a resource for a long time, you already did something wrong. Trying to acquire the second lock with a timeout is pointing into the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217133/discussion-between-boyu-zhang-and-holger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach using `tryLock` is heading into the direction of a deadlock free solution. But you have to ensure that the lock is correctly closed in the exceptional case. Further, since a `tryLock` may fail, leading to the action not being performed, you need to return a status:

```
class Account {
    private int balance;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    boolean transfer(Account target, int amt) {
        boolean success = false;
        //lock the from account
        try {
            if(lock.tryLock(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) try {
                if(target.lock.tryLock(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) try {
                    this.balance -= amt;
                    target.balance += amt;
                    success = true;
                }
                finally {
                    target.lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            // success still false
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

Then, you have to consider how to deal with a failure, retrying the operation or giving up. This leads to another problem, the so called livelock problem. When a thread tries to transfer from A to B while another tries to transfer from B to A, both may succeed in locking their source, followed by failing to lock the other. Repeating the attempt may repeatedly result in failure. Similar scenarios involving more threads are possible. In these scenarios, no deadlock occurs, but the threads still can’t make progress.

The solution is similar to another approach for avoiding deadlocks: always acquire locks in a predefined order.

```
class Account {
    final BigInteger accountNumber;
    private int balance;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    Account(BigInteger accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    void transfer(Account target, int amt) {
        if(accountNumber.compareTo(target.accountNumber) < 0)
            transfer(this, target, amt);
        else
            transfer(target, this, -amt);
    }

    static void transfer(Account from, Account to, int amt) {
        from.lock.lock();
        try {
            to.lock.lock();
            try {
                from.balance -= amt;
                to.balance += amt;
            }
            finally {
                to.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        finally {
            from.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

By always locking the account with the smaller number first, we can never encounter a scenario where another thread owning the bigger number’s lock tries to acquire the lock we already own.